# Firebase prints Analytics SSL error, however Analytics is not being used

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an iOS 12 Swift app that uses Firebase. I am only using the following firebase pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.4'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.4'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.4'
```

I am not using Firebase Analytics but I think it is bundled with the `Firebase/Core` pod.

**Error message:**

```
5.4.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901017] Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "Se ha producido un error de SSL y no puede establecerse una conexión segura con el servidor." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/a, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=¿Quieres conectarte al servidor de todos modos?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask <699995C5-0868-4814-BE8C-4273D8CDBE63>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalUploadTask <699995C5-0868-4814-BE8C-4273D8CDBE63>.<1>"
```

The localized error message is written in Spanish. It says something like `"An SSL error has been produced and it wasn't possible to establish a secure connection with the server."`

I do not have Analytics enabled in my app and I don't reference it in any of my code. I want to implement this in the future, but while this happens ¿Can I stop getting this very annoying message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics)

> **Permanently deactivate collection**
>
> If you need to deactivate Analytics collection permanently in a version of your app, set 
>   `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED` to YES in your app's Info.plist file.
>   Setting FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED to YES takes priority over any values for FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED in your app's Info.plist as well as any values set with setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled.
>
> **Temporarily disable collection**
>
> `AnalyticsConfiguration.shared().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)`